# Firebase doesn't apply data rules after logging in

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, rules, rights

I have a big but simple security problem with angularfire.

https://jsfiddle.net/nicolas1000/ea0L9x44/

You can also test it there :
http://nicolash.org/truc44/

well my goal is simply that as soon as any user log in, the Data Model appears in the application, (taking advantage of the 3 ways binding.)

I've got these security rules applied in the firebase dashboard :

```
  {
  "rules": {
    // public read access
    ".read": false,
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        // write access only to your own data
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The anonymous loggin session works

But, the rules don't apply. I can't see my "VILLES" data model appear on the page.

This is my unique controller, who works well :

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray', "$firebaseAuth", function ($scope,$firebaseArray, $firebaseAuth) {


var ref = new Firebase("https://blinding-heat-8502.firebaseio.com/villes"); 
                auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

                $scope.login = function() {
                  $scope.authData = null;
                  $scope.error = null;

                  auth.$authAnonymously().then(function(authData) {
                    $scope.authData = authData;
                    $scope.villes = $firebaseArray(ref);

                  }).catch(function(error) {
                    $scope.error = error;

                  });
                };
```

}])

I'm still getting this error, trying to fetch the data into $scope.villes, while i'm logged in successfully:

```
Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

My villes data structure look like this and is really simple : an Array of cities with one name that's all !:

```
villes
-K7RMScvACBfJC_ebW1p  
 name : New York
```

Maybe i need to mention a $uid into eachs of the cities ? Please help thank you.

**EDIT :** *Ok i think it's resolved ! Ouf !*

**FIRST :** Changed the Firebase rules to this :

{"rules": {"villes": {".read": "auth != null",".write": "auth != null"} }}

**SECOND :** Under the LOGIN AND AUTH tab in the firebase dashboard, I've  Changed the session length to 20 seconds, and it works ! As soon as somebody isn't logged any more, he's not able to access the firebase branche called "VILLES" into firebase any more.

thanks a lot

Comment: There's way too much code in your question for us to digest the problem quickly. StackOverflow is not a debugging service. If you have a problem, reproduce it outside of your application with the minimal code to completely get the problematic behavior. Then that's the code to post here (and a link to a jsfiddle or something wouldn't hurt either). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you a lot, i will try to remove the not necessary code. I thought it was an easy problem to solve, sorry.

Comment: I am also not a debugger. : (

Comment: Hi i've updated my example, this is not an application, i can't make it work, do you think it's a rule problem ? thank you. I really can't make the security rules works.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nicolas1000/ea0L9x44/

Comment: Changed my rules to {
  "rules": {
    "villes": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
} still doesnt work, i'm able to see the data while i'm not logged